# The triggers fail after the project is published

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

I created an add-on project for Google Sheets, which has some triggers, it ran flawlessly. However, after being published by Google, when a user runs the program, he receives an error message: "This add-on has created too many time-based triggers in this document for this Google user account".
My triggers:

Set time to Google Form

```
function stopFormRespones() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
for (var l = 2; l <= ss.getSheetByName('listStudent').getLastRow(); l++) {
  var link = ss.getSheetByName('listStudent').getRange('N'+l).getValue();
  var form = FormApp.openByUrl(link);
form.setAcceptingResponses(false);
}
}

function openFormRespones() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
for (var l = 2; l <= ss.getSheetByName('listStudent').getLastRow(); l++) {
  var link = ss.getSheetByName('listStudent').getRange('N'+l).getValue();
var form = FormApp.openByUrl(link);
form.setAcceptingResponses(true);
}
}

function scheduledCollection(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var start = ss.getSheetByName('title').getRange('F12').getValue();
  var end = ss.getSheetByName('title').getRange('F14').getValue();
  var t = new Date();
  if (t > start & t < end) {
  openFormRespones();
  }
  else {
  stopFormRespones();
  }
}

function StartStop(){
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var start = ss.getSheetByName('title').getRange('F12').getValue();
  var end = ss.getSheetByName('title').getRange('F14').getValue();
  var limit = ScriptApp.newTrigger('scheduledCollection')
              .timeBased()
              .everyMinutes(1)
              .create();
}
```

Run a function

```
function triggerMix() {
  var hour = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('title').getRange('AH7').getValue();
  var autoMix = ScriptApp.newTrigger('mix1')
    .timeBased()
    .atHour(hour)
    .everyDays(1)
    .create();
}
```

How can I make adjustments in my script project?
Is the number of triggers allocated to the developer for all users or per user?
Please help!

Comment: Why do you need more than one trigger?

Comment: Actually in my project I have to run multiple functions at once (mix1(), mix2(), mix3(),...), so I have to set the trigger.

Comment: How many triggers do you need? 20 is the maximum per user per script https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas

Comment: Maybe you should considered combining some into one or possibly all into one

Comment: Thanks to Cooper and iansedano,
Because if I combine multiple functions into one the runtime exceeds the allowed time, so I have to use triggers to run the functions at different times.
I mean that this project I use will run fine with all triggers, but my add-on user gets the error as stated above.

Comment: Are you deleting the old triggers as you create new ones? Your script may be running slow because you are getting a range and value for each cell, this is very slow. My answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66365218/10445017) may help you in this regard.

Comment: Also, see https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable - `an add-on can use a time-driven trigger once per hour at most` so it looks like you will have to optimize your code. Can you share the part that takes the longest?

Comment: Thanks iansedano,
The most time consuming part is running the functions mix1 (), mix2 (), .... I have a lot of such functions. Actually, my project is to create many Forms, but because the time to create the Form exceeds the time allowed, I have to use the trigger from time to do it. I don't know how to replace that method. Can you help me?

Comment: Can you share the code of `mix1` and `mix2` to get an idea of what they do?

Comment: I solved the 6 minute time limit with continueFileIterator (). However, the StartStop () function for the add-on is not allowed. It repeats every minute. While it is only allowed to repeat after at least 1 hour.

Comment: @ĐìnhTấnNguyễn  please share the code from mix1 and mix2 and whatever code has the `continueFileIterator()`